# How to make hibernate hbm2ddl generate SQL with semicolon?

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

I use hibernate hbm2ddl to generate db schema script from entity classes. It works well but each line ends without a semicolon, which makes me have to manually add them. Is there any way to save me from this stupid job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using SchemaExport directly it is simple:

```
new SchemaExport(config).setDelimiter(";").Execute(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/appendices/Configurations.html) to `;` in your Hibernate properties, or set [`AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_DELIMITER`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#HBM2DDL_DELIMITER) to `;` if you're configuring Hibernate programmatically.